# How to release terraform state lock file from GCP backend when using automation for deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

While running terraform in automation (google cloud build trigger), for some reason I have to stop or cancel the pipeline, which resulted in lock on my state file.

I understand that the process to unlock the state file is `terraform force-unlock id`.
I do got the id, now the issue is **where I have to run the said command.**
As I am using cloud build trigger and not cloud shell or local machine to initiate / plan / apply, thus trying to understand where to run the above command.

Terraform Backend : GCP Storage Bucket

Terraform : >= 0.14

google : = 4.18.0

Please suggest, how to release the lock file in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the access to run terraform commands but have the permissions to the Google Cloud Storage bucket that's used as the backend, you can remove `.tflock` file which will release the lock.

Make sure that the lock id corresponds to the lock id shown in the error message.

Comment: Thanks @ollimandoliini, yes I did deleted the .tflock file and re-ran the terraform apply command, and it worked perfectly fine. Was bit sceptic on the change.